# How to get a map without labels?

Tags: google-maps

I want to get a map (I only need a picture) that has the road network
but without labels (text on the map). I tried to get such a map from Google API and thought `"element:geometry"`
works.

But, for example, [this link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=512x512&center=Brooklyn&style=element%3ageometry) is still full of texts.

How can I obtain a road network map (static picture is ok) without text labels?
Any provider is ok, e.g. Google, Yahoo, Mapquest...

Comment: These solutions work for 'roadmap' and for 'satellite' .  I am trying to get a StreetView without street names.  I have been reading the API documentation but could not find how to remove labels on streetview.  Any clues?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use this style:

```
style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off
```

it will hide all labels for all features.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=512x512&center=Brooklyn&zoom=12&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=28.459033,22.060547&zoom=2&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap&style=feature:administrative|weight:0.1|invert_lightness:true|visibility:off&style=feature:water|element:labels.text|visibility:off&style=feature:landscape.natural|visibility:on

Answer (score 5):

I got a better solution:

Create a html file and insert the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mapa GMR Norte</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
      {
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
      }
    ], {
      name: 'Custom Style'
  });
  var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 41.4416459, lng: -8.2911885},  // Brooklyn.
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId]
    }
  });

  map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 5):

The Google Maps Styled Map Wizard (link below) will allow you to remove labels (and also make tons of other customizations).

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: The link is the Google Maps Styled Map Wizard. If that link is unavailable then my answer is invalid.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *Error 404 (Not Found)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The link is working and Google will suggest using cloud-based Map Styling, but you need to be logged into Google Cloud Console. Cloud-based Map Styling offers a lot more customisation.

Answer (score 4):

[This is the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html) on map styling for the JavaScript API. There's also a [Styled Map Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) that lets you play with the styles to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, I see that document. They said "element:geometry selects only geometric elements of that feature.
element:labels selects only textual labels associated with that feature." I only want geometric element (road network) and avoid textual labels. So I use "element:geometry". But it does not remove text on map.

Answer (score 0):

by "I only need a picture" I take it you don't need to access to API, Google Inc devs still didn't a chance to apply all the features from the old maps to the new design.
However you can still access it by going to https://maps.google.com/?output=classic

and you can go to settings and customise "tick labels off" and so forth...