# iOS Google Maps SDK - Hide / remove labels

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using Google Maps SDK in my iOS project. I am using Swift and **I want to display the Google Map in UIView without any text or labels.** I am able to display the map correctly but I am not able to remove the text from the map... I saw the same problem in Javascript but was unable to replicate it in Swift ([How to get a map without labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444790/how-to-get-a-map-without-labels))... I want the regular type of the map (kGMSTypeNormal). Is there some way how to do it?

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431602/how-to-hide-default-labels-on-google-maps-ios-sdk

Comment: @W.K.S yes, I saw that, I just hoped they code it in recent two years :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible to hide the `labels`, `landmarks` and `roads`.

```
do {
     // Set the map style by passing the URL of the local file.
     if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mapStyle", withExtension: "json") {
           self.mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
      } else {
           print("Unable to find style.json")
      }
   } catch {
       print("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
  }
```

Where [mapStyle.json](https://gist.github.com/TheTiger13/a0e94e1630463bac2f2536c63304f7f9) is a json file in my project. For more detail see [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/hiding-features).

Comment: i did not test your code but seems that after two years it is possible now :-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no direct answer for this feature yet. I can only think of 2 possible options namely:

1. Use [Satellite view](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#map_types). It has no labels/texts whatsoever.

   mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
2. Use [Custom Tile Overlays/Layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/tiles)

> Tile layers (sometimes referred to as Tile Overlays) allow you to
>   superimpose images on top of Google's base map tiles. This is an
>   excellent way to add data - such as points of interest or traffic
>   information - and local imagery to your app. When combined with the
>   kGMSTypeNone map type, tile layers effectively let you replace
>   Google's base map data with your own.