# How to remove default marker from GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I used GMSMapView for iOS app. I want to remove default marker/annotation from GMSMapView but it's not removed. I use maptype property to remove it which is working perfect in Android but in iOS it's not working. Let me share code sample here.

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: zoom)
mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: rect, camera: camera)
mapView.mapType = .terrain //<--- it's not working somehow in code i have tried all options.
```

Is there any other way to remove all default marker/annotation from GMSMapView in iOS?
Let me attached image for visibility.
[screen shot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAF20.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer this ans i have tested its working

[iOS Google Maps SDK - Hide / remove labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032936/ios-google-maps-sdk-hide-remove-labels)

first add myStyle.json file in your project and then call the do catch

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the map's style and you can do that with a JSON file in the app's bundle. Those markers are POI markers and you can remove them entirely with the following:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

JSON generator: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

API reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/style-reference